# what should a React checkbox alike component expose as API?

Tags: reactjs, redux, mobx

I am building a component, basically like a *checkbox*, but customized design.

My component is like

```js
class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   checked: false
  };
 }
 toggle(){
  this.setState({
   checked: !this.state.checked
  });
 }
 render() {
  return (
   <svg onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}>
   <circle cx={50} cy={50} r={30} fill={this.state.checked ? "green" : "red"} />
   </svg>
  )
 }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

What would be the correct way to handle state so that I can use either Mobx or Redux state managing? In other words: how can I make this component agnostic to state management and enable state being changed from outside the component?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [React's form element API](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html). A similar approach to this seems reasonable for a custom component.

React's form elements have two basic operating modes, **controlled** and **uncontrolled**.

**Controlled:** The component exposes a `value` property and a `onChange` handler. It does not handle its own state, but always represents the state determined by `value`. If the user toggles the checkbox, you would call the change handler, and it is the task of the wrapping component to change the `value` property accordingly.

**Uncontrolled:** The component also exposes a `onChange` handler, but no `value` property. It handles its own state and basically only informs the wrapping component about the changed state via the change handler. You would pass an initial value using the `initialValue` property.

Which approach fits your needs better depends on your use case. Generally, **controlled** components are the recommended approach.

Comment: TimoSta, thank you for the answer! When you mean "expose" the value do you mean having a this.state.value and that can be used from outside the component? or how to "expose" the value, by allowing setState to be called from outside?

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up to TimoSta's answer, I thought it'd be helpful to give a quick demonstration of how what he's suggesting could be implemented:

```
import React from "react";

class ControlledCheckbox extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    onChange() {
        if (this.props.onChange) {
            this.props.onChange(!this.props.value);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.onChange}>
                {this.props.value ? "✓" : "✗"}
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Note that this component doesn't hold any state whatsoever - it simply takes a value in, and passes events back up.

Comment: Interesting... and how can we change the this.props.value from outside the component?

Comment: @Rikard: Same way you change any other prop: `<ControlledCheckbox value={foo} />` - when the value of `foo` changes, your checkbox updates.